# Binary number to decimal (doesn't work well, why?)

Tags: c#, binary, decimal

Hy guys!
I have written this, but doesn't work well, it's irritating me. I tried to find the solution but I didn't find the any errors in it.

```
    private string binaris_decimalis(string binaris_szam)
    {
        char[] binaris_karakterek = binaris_szam.ToCharArray();

        int decimalis_szam_int = 0;
        string decimalis_szam;

        for (int szam = 0; binaris_karakterek.Length > szam; szam++)
        {
            decimalis_szam_int = decimalis_szam_int * 2 + Convert.ToInt32(binaris_karakterek[szam]);
        }

        decimalis_szam = Convert.ToString(decimalis_szam_int);

        return decimalis_szam;
    }
```

Used like this:

```
    private void valtas_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        binaris_szam_2 = binaris_2.Text.Split('.');

        for (int szam = 0; 4 > szam; szam++)
        {
            decimalis_szam_2[szam] = binaris_decimalis(binaris_szam_2[szam]);
        }

        decimalis_2.Text = decimalis_szam_2[0] + "." + decimalis_szam_2[1] + "." + decimalis_szam_2[2] + "." + decimalis_szam_2[3];
    }
```

binaris_szam_2 and decimalis_szam2 is declarated as public string[]:

```
string[] binaris_szam_2 = new string[4];
string[] decimalis_szam_2 = new string[4];
```

The text input looks like:

> 10000000.10000000.10000000.10000000

The text output should looks like:

> 128.128.128.128

But the output is:

> 12368.12368.12368.12368

I would be grateful if someone could help me!

Comment: The core problem is the `Convert.ToInt32` on your `char` values. These won't represent "0" or "1", but the `char` integer representations of them -- that is "48" and "49" respectively completely throwing off the math. Regardless, Luis Tellez's answer is far simpler to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know whats wrong with your code but you can do this directly with c#.

```
Convert.ToInt32("10000000", 2).ToString(); // output  128
```

Comment: I didn't know this function of Convert.ToInt32, thanks for your assistance!